# Plot3D appears differently while creating and displaying

Tags: graphics3d

I have some data that represents the end points of a series of `Cuboid`s and use a `Module` to plot it. I assign a symbol, `tmpPlot` to the output of the `Module`.

The figure that is displayed as the output of the `Module` differs from when I simply type the symbol.

The color data I use is

```
colorList = Module[
   {
    firstHalf = 15,
    secondHalf =30
    },
   secondHalf = secondHalf - firstHalf;
   firstHalf = firstHalf - 1;
   secondHalf = secondHalf - 1;
   Join[
    Map[Blend[{Blue, Green}, #] &, Range[0, firstHalf]/firstHalf],
    Map[Blend[{Green, Red}, #] &, Range[0, secondHalf]/secondHalf]
    ]
   ];
```

The data is (apologize for the verbosity)

```
data = {{{{0, 4, 0}, {20, 8, 31.66}}, {{20, 4, 0}, {40, 
      8, -3.34}}, {{40, 4, 0}, {60, 8, -16.11}}, {{60, 4, 0}, {80, 8, 
      23.23}}, {{80, 4, 0}, {100, 8, -17.34}}}, {{{0, 8, 0}, {20, 12, 
      29.24}}, {{20, 8, 0}, {40, 12, -5.35}}, {{40, 8, 0}, {60, 
      12, -3.85}}}, {{{0, 12, 0}, {20, 16, 30.96}}, {{20, 12, 0}, {40,
       16, 9.88}}, {{40, 12, 0}, {60, 16, -3.55}}}, {{{0, 16, 0}, {20,
       20, -1.93}}, {{20, 16, 0}, {40, 20, 3.77}}, {{40, 16, 0}, {60, 
      20, -1.3}}}, {{{0, 20, 0}, {20, 24, -3.23}}, {{20, 20, 0}, {40, 
      24, 0.48}}}, {{{0, 24, 0}, {20, 28, 0.02}}, {{20, 24, 0}, {40, 
      28, 0.9}}, {{40, 24, 0}, {60, 28, 0.01}}, {{60, 24, 0}, {80, 28,
       0.72}}, {{80, 24, 0}, {100, 28, 1.29}}}, {{{0, 28, 0}, {20, 
      32, -8.92}}, {{20, 28, 0}, {40, 32, 3.62}}, {{40, 28, 0}, {60, 
      32, -1.75}}, {{60, 28, 0}, {80, 32, 4.71}}, {{80, 28, 0}, {100, 
      32, 2.89}}}, {{{40, 32, 0}, {60, 36, -0.05}}, {{60, 32, 0}, {80,
       36, 2.18}}, {{80, 32, 0}, {100, 36, 2.95}}}, {{{20, 36, 
      0}, {40, 40, 4.69}}, {{40, 36, 0}, {60, 40, -0.04}}, {{60, 36, 
      0}, {80, 40, 2.33}}, {{80, 36, 0}, {100, 40, 3.08}}}, {{{0, 40, 
      0}, {20, 44, -3.06}}, {{20, 40, 0}, {40, 44, 6.1}}, {{40, 40, 
      0}, {60, 44, 0.34}}, {{60, 40, 0}, {80, 44, 2.44}}, {{80, 40, 
      0}, {100, 44, 3.52}}}, {{{80, 44, 0}, {100, 48, 5.68}}}, {{{80, 
      48, 0}, {100, 52, 6.63}}}, {{{0, 52, 0}, {20, 56, 15.42}}, {{20,
       52, 0}, {40, 56, 3.59}}, {{40, 52, 0}, {60, 56, -1.92}}, {{60, 
      52, 0}, {80, 56, 9.71}}, {{80, 52, 0}, {100, 56, 7.68}}}, {{{0, 
      56, 0}, {20, 60, -4.33}}, {{20, 56, 0}, {40, 60, 15.52}}, {{40, 
      56, 0}, {60, 60, 4.18}}, {{60, 56, 0}, {80, 60, 1.38}}, {{80, 
      56, 0}, {100, 60, 8.03}}}, {{{0, 60, 0}, {20, 
      64, -22.03}}, {{20, 60, 0}, {40, 64, 18.89}}, {{40, 60, 0}, {60,
       64, 8.75}}, {{60, 60, 0}, {80, 64, 9.57}}}, {{{0, 64, 0}, {20, 
      68, 42.08}}, {{20, 64, 0}, {40, 68, -3.34}}, {{40, 64, 0}, {60, 
      68, -5.09}}, {{60, 64, 0}, {80, 68, 9.77}}}, {{{0, 68, 0}, {20, 
      72, 11.09}}, {{20, 68, 0}, {40, 72, -2.76}}, {{40, 68, 0}, {60, 
      72, -7.88}}, {{60, 68, 0}, {80, 72, 1.1}}, {{80, 68, 0}, {100, 
      72, 14.22}}}, {{{0, 72, 0}, {20, 76, 38.97}}, {{20, 72, 0}, {40,
       76, 6.51}}, {{40, 72, 0}, {60, 76, -4.11}}, {{60, 72, 0}, {80, 
      76, 19.81}}, {{80, 72, 0}, {100, 76, 14.85}}}, {{{60, 76, 
      0}, {80, 80, 9.98}}, {{80, 76, 0}, {100, 80, 15.42}}}, {{{0, 80,
       0}, {20, 84, 29.19}}, {{20, 80, 0}, {40, 84, 13.66}}, {{40, 80,
       0}, {60, 84, -0.85}}, {{60, 80, 0}, {80, 84, 20.14}}, {{80, 80,
       0}, {100, 84, 15.6}}}, {{{0, 84, 0}, {20, 88, 33.34}}, {{20, 
      84, 0}, {40, 88, 14.41}}, {{40, 84, 0}, {60, 88, -0.4}}, {{60, 
      84, 0}, {80, 88, 10.31}}, {{80, 84, 0}, {100, 88, 
      16.38}}}, {{{0, 88, 0}, {20, 92, 31.45}}, {{20, 88, 0}, {40, 92,
       13.22}}, {{40, 88, 0}, {60, 92, -4.75}}, {{60, 88, 0}, {80, 92,
       16.5}}}, {{{0, 92, 0}, {20, 96, 3.44}}, {{20, 92, 0}, {40, 
      96, -6.30}}, {{40, 92, 0}, {60, 96, -14.44}}, {{60, 92, 0}, {80,
       96, 13.77}}, {{80, 92, 0}, {100, 96, 18.68}}}, {{{0, 96, 
      0}, {20, 100, 13.}}, {{20, 96, 0}, {40, 100, -4.23}}, {{40, 96, 
      0}, {60, 100, -4.65}}, {{60, 96, 0}, {80, 100, 6.58}}, {{80, 96,
       0}, {100, 100, 23.2}}}, {{{60, 100, 0}, {80, 104, 
      24.95}}}, {{{0, 104, 0}, {20, 108, 36.17}}, {{20, 104, 0}, {40, 
      108, 6.99}}, {{40, 104, 0}, {60, 108, -4.61}}, {{60, 104, 
      0}, {80, 108, 27.88}}}, {{{0, 108, 0}, {20, 112, 28.6}}, {{20, 
      108, 0}, {40, 112, 6.21}}, {{40, 108, 0}, {60, 112, 
      6.82}}, {{60, 108, 0}, {80, 112, -2.93}}, {{80, 108, 0}, {100, 
      112, 30.48}}}, {{{0, 112, 0}, {20, 116, 26.39}}, {{20, 112, 
      0}, {40, 116, -9.05}}, {{60, 112, 0}, {80, 116, -8.49}}, {{80, 
      112, 0}, {100, 116, 32.99}}}, {{{0, 116, 0}, {20, 120, 
      4.1}}, {{20, 116, 0}, {40, 120, -1.7}}, {{40, 116, 0}, {60, 
      120, -13.55}}, {{60, 116, 0}, {80, 120, 13.19}}, {{80, 116, 
      0}, {100, 120, 35.19}}}, {{{0, 120, 0}, {20, 124, 17.4}}, {{20, 
      120, 0}, {40, 124, 11.56}}, {{40, 120, 0}, {60, 
      124, -26.35}}, {{60, 120, 0}, {80, 124, 16.}}, {{80, 120, 
      0}, {100, 124, 45.8}}}};
```

Here is the `Module` and the output figure

```
tmpPlot = Module[
  {
   xaxisMax = 101,
   yaxisMax = 128,
   zaxisScales = {-30, 50}
   },

  Graphics3D[
   Map[
    {FaceForm[colorList[[#]]],
      data[[#]] /. {{x1_Integer, y1_Integer, z1_}, {x2_Integer, 
          y2_Integer, z2_}} ->
        Cuboid[{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}]
      } &,
    Range[Length[data]]
    ],
   PlotRange -> {{0, xaxisMax}, {0, yaxisMax}, zaxisScales},
   Axes -> True,
   AxesEdge -> {{1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}},
   AxesLabel -> {Style["y-axis", Bold, 14], 
     Style[ "x-axis", Bold, 14], Style["z-axis", Bold, 14]},
   PlotLabel -> Style["PlotLabel", 16, Blue],
   ViewPoint -> {1.7, -0.3, 2.8},
   ImageSize -> {800, 600},
   AspectRatio -> 3/4
   ]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I simply type `tmpPlot` the figure is displayed differently.

```
tmpPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The question is, why the difference in the two displays?

Comment: Is this difference only the `ViewPoint` or is there something else you're seeing?

Comment: I replaced `allSecurites` with numbers (sorry). I am on Mathematica 11.3  running on Windows 7. I have repeated it several times and get plots that look slightly different (as in the snapshots).

Comment: I get identical looking plots on my Mac with the updated code.  Maybe it's a Window's thing.